# Why cloudfront distribution not listing elastic load balancer in HongKong region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb, aws-regions

I am creating a Cloud Front distribution in AWS. I have a ELB created in Hong Kong region.
When I am selecting Origin Domain, My ELB in Hong Kong region is not coming in drop down. While, I tried with creating ELB in N.Virginia region and it is visible.

Is there any such restrictions imposed by AWS or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: see Michi's response: any publicly accessible URL will work as a CloudFront origin—it does not have to appear in the dropdown. The AWS console dropdown is limited to what origin types and potentially AWS regions are loaded by default. But no concerns with using it as an origin if you manually add the URL.

Answer (score 2):

I replicated the setup you described in my own AWS account and it happened there as well: The ELB did not show up in the Origin list. While I am not sure why this is the case, an easy workaround for you is to just manually enter the ELB's DNS name as the Origin. My test ELB had the DNS record test-1224452099.ap-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com, so I put http://test-1224452099.ap-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com as the Origin for my CloudFront Distribution. That worked. For production use, above URL should of course be HTTPS, not HTTP.

Please note: You might have to edit the rules of the ELB's security group if the ELB is not reachable from CloudFront. You can use a managed prefix list for this: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/02/amazon-cloudfront-managed-prefix-list/

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if your CloudFront Origin is on your on-premise data center https://mydatacenter.example.com this should normally will not appear in the CF Origin list but it should work as long as the website is publicly accessible.